# How to run multiples contracts functionalities in a single contract Solidity

Tags: solidity

I'm new to Solidity but I can't find much information about my problem.
For example, I want to make different contracts for different functionalities (I see them as classes)
For example

Main contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: None
pragma solidity >=0.8.6;

import "./AuthContract.sol";

contract Contract {
    string public message;

    constructor() {
      message = "test";
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns(string memory) {
      return message;
    }
}
```

and second contract

```
contract Auth {
    struct UserDetail {
        address addr;
        string name;
        string password;
        string CNIC;
        bool isUserLoggedIn;
    }

    mapping(address => UserDetail) user;

    // user registration function
    function register(
        address _address,
        string memory _name,
        string memory _password,
        string memory _cnic
    ) public returns (bool) {
        require(user[_address].addr != msg.sender);
        user[_address].addr = _address;
        user[_address].name = _name;
        user[_address].password = _password;
        user[_address].CNIC = _cnic;
        user[_address].isUserLoggedIn = false;
        return true;
    }

    // user login function
    function login(address _address, string memory _password)
        public
        returns (bool)
    {
        if (
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(user[_address].password)) ==
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_password))
        ) {
            user[_address].isUserLoggedIn = true;
            return user[_address].isUserLoggedIn;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // check the user logged In or not
    function checkIsUserLogged(address _address) public view returns (bool) {
        return (user[_address].isUserLoggedIn);
    }

    // logout the user
    function logout(address _address) public {
        user[_address].isUserLoggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

How could I use the functionalities from that contract in the main contract?
Is such a thing possible in the blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new here also but i can solve your problem, if not solve i can lead you to a good path .
so firstly you said you want to create multiple contract for different functionalities, this is good but keep in my you are going to exhaust a lot of gas.
so the answer to your problem is easy you can just read it and implement it.
if you want to use a contract in the Another contract (main in your case) you can do it in two ways(according to my knowledge there might be other).

1. using new keyword
2. using address of your previously deployed contract
   we will be using the First case as i suppose you havenot deployed the second contract yet
   In Order to do it you can use

   `Auth myObj=new Auth();`

This will create a new instance of the contract Auth in your main contract and now you can use the Auth contract's function in your Main contract.you can create a function copy the above line and you can use the Functions using dot operator.

```
myObj.register(_address,_name,moreandmore);
```

I believe this will solve your problem if not you can ask it.
Thank You!

Comment: But for example if I want to set something like that:
Child contract
```
string public name;

    function getName() public view returns(string memory) {
        return name;
    }

    function setName(string memory _value) public {
        name = _value;
    }
```
Main contract
```
function setName(string memory _value) public {
    authContract.setName(_value);
  }

  function getName() public view {
    authContract.getName();
  }
```
For the set I receive

Comment: Send data to method 'setName' with ["test"] from 0x1Bb9D90b581a727d2845A03FFe3247e45B104C69 at contract address 0x2a59D9aA51eF97380B81e387F5BcA0d14723d14c
And for get

Comment: Calling method 'getName' with [] from 0x1Bb9D90b581a727d2845A03FFe3247e45B104C69 at contract address 0x2a59D9aA51eF97380B81e387F5BcA0d14723d14c
[3:04:39 PM]: {}

Comment: Do I really need to send an address?

Comment: sorry the problem is in your above code you are not getting the data from getName() (of the AUTH contract)because your getName() of main contract has not any returns statement!. so add a return statement .

Comment: and you don't need to send any address if you are using new statement and don't forget to import the contract otherwise you will not be able to use the AUTH